# Programmatically list folders from a document library

Tags: 2013, web-part, document-library

I have a document library with several layers of folders within, I'm trying to populate a dropdownlist in a web part to display a tree like display of the folders but my code

```
    foreach(SPListItem lItem in docLibrary.Items)
    {
        if (lItem.Folder == null) {}
        else
        {
            ListItem ddlItem = new ListItem(lItem.Name, lItem.ID.ToString());
        }
    }
```

In my testing library I have two folders with one file in the second folder, when this loop executes it retrieves the count of ListItems as 3 but only ever iterates once, how can I make the list iterate and pick up the folders?

Answer (score 4):

This code iterates all sub folder of your root folder and gets items by your query from subfolders

```
foreach (SPFolder subFolder in docLibrary.RootFolder.SubFolders)
{
     SPQuery oQuery = new SPQuery();
     oQuery.Query = "Your Query"
     oQuery.Folder = subFolder;                               
     collListItems = oList.GetItems(oQuery);                                
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I found that you can just use `docLibrary.Folders` instead of `docLibrary.Items` and it returns an `SPListItemCollection` containing only the folders.